# SVG filter is cut off when the SVG is positioned over an element with translate3d

Tags: google-chrome, svg, svg-filters

I have an SVG element that is absolute positioned, and whenever it is positioned over top an element that uses transform: translate3d(x, y, z) the drop shadow filter I have applied to it is cut off. This doesn't happen on Firefox but it does on chrome.

I made a Stackblitz of the issue: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/svg-filter-cutoff?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: maybe best to raise a [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) unless there already is one.

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering an edge case bug in Chrome that seems to occur only with a 0,0,0 translate. If you add a pixel of translation in any axis (e.g. transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1)) - it goes away.